# Are there non-Diggles in Diggle Hell?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I am doing a Vegan run, and a consequence of this is that Diggles don't attack me (they are classified as Animals). Is every creature that can appear in Diggle Hell a Diggle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, there are non-Animals in Diggle Hell - [Mini-boss Vlad Digula](https://community.gaslampgames.com/threads/vlad-digulas-stats-good-lord.4815/) is not considered Animal:

[image: Vlad Digula]

He is also very tough guy, meeting him may quickly end one's permadeath run.